# Web wallet best practices

Tags: web3js, security, private-key, keystore, design-patterns

I'm putting together an ether/erc20 token wallet in a chrome extension but would like to follow best practices with regards to private key security.

I'm using localstorage to handle login and its contents are as follows

```
Localstorage (no account):
    (empty)

Localstorage (signed out):
    password hash
    encrypted private key

Localstorage( signed in):
    password hash
    decrypted private key
    expiry timestamp for decrypted private key
```

is there anything intrinsically dangerous about this?
I'm using npm packages web3v1 (beta) and crypto-js

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean localstorage as in HTML5 localstorage?

If so I personally would not store a users private key in localStorage.

A malicious piece of javascript such as this,

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
  $('body').append(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
}
```

which will use the key method in localStorage.key(index) which returns the index th key to loop through localStorage in a browser and read out all the values.

From my understanding localStorage stays unless you clear it.  Perhaps for the last use case use sessionStorage

```
Localstorage (no account):
    (empty)

Localstorage (signed out):
    password hash
    encrypted private key

Sessionstorage( signed in):
    password hash
    decrypted private key
    expiry timestamp for decrypted private key
```

That way on browser/session close  the decrypted private key will disappear.

Comment: how would that malicious javascript enter the page

Answer (score 1):

I would advice against building your own wallet if you don't have the appropriate security expertise. There are many things that can go terrible wrong when handling secrets in a frontend, a single xss can leak all the secrets, the wrong design approach can leave your extension open to the mercy of any malicious site your user visit ..etc. That said, *if you must* create a new wallet you should checkout how metamask browser extension is designed and implemented https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension. Metamask has gone through multiple rounds of security review, and has a solid community validation.